# How to use AT commands for switch 2G only Huawei E220 modem

Tags: linux, gsm, at-command, modem, huawei-mobile-services

Hey everyone I'm new with AT commands, maybe someone can help which command I need to send with minicom to the modem for switching it to 2g gsm mode only?

Comment: [AT Command Interface Specification - Huawei](http://download-c.huawei.com/download/downloadCenter?downloadId=51047&version=120450&siteCode)

Comment: Please state a language and show your code. It is no different than your other question at [How to make Huawei E220 modem 2G only Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52914759/608639)